# Use default container but custom comparator in priority_queue

Tags: c++, c++14, priority-queue, template-specialization

Is is possible to use a `priority_queue` with the default container type, but a custom comparator?

In other words, how do I get around specifying `vector` here?

```
auto cmp = [](int a, int b){ return a > b; };
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> my_queue(cmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. This is the same as function parameter defaults where you have to specify parameter `a` before being able to specify parameter `b` even if both have default values and you want to keep `a` as default, like:

```
void foo(int a = 5, int b = 42);
```

You could make a helper that creates such a queue but in the end you'll still have to specify the 2nd argument, even if you just want the default.

Something like:

```
template <typename T, typename Comp>
using default_priority_queue = std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, Comp>;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about explicitly mentioning `std::vector` you could write something like this:

```
priority_queue<int, priority_queue<int>::container_type, decltype(cmp)> my_queue(cmp);
```

though, I dont believe priority queue getting a different default container is really an issue and simply writing vector is actually shorter than that.